# updating class object from main function Python

Tags: python, function, class, dictionary, object

I have a book library program that it's class reads a file containing `ID` and `name` and assign them to self objects as `id` and `card holder`. then there is self object for borrowed books, so then I can identify which user borrowed which book.
The problem is in `main` function when a user return a book, I don't know how to update the self borrowed book object to delete that book from the object, so the self `id` will not have books borrowed to it.

Here is how the class looks:

```
    #loan time length is 3 weeks by default
    LOAN_TIME = 3
    
    class Librarycard:
    
        def __init__(self, card_id, card_holder):
    
    
            self.__id = card_id
            self.__holder = card_holder
    
            #a dictionary that will contain the full book : loan time, updated in later function
            self.__loan = {}
    
        def return_book(self, book):
    
            del self.__loan[book]
            print('returned')
            return
```

and this is my `main` function part which concern the book loaning:

```
    def main():
    
        command = input("Command: ")
        
        #borrowed books main list to check if book borrowed or not
        borrowed_books = []
        
                if command == "R":
        
                    book = input("Book code: ")
        
                    if book not in borrowed_books:
                        print('This book has not been borrowed by anyone')
        
                    else:
                        del borrowed_books[book]
                        print('book returned')
                        
                        # this is where I try to enter the function from the class to update the object 
                        # dictionary 
                        book.return_book(book)
    
    if __name__ == "__main__":
        main()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Librarycard:

    def __init__(self, card_id, card_holder):
        self.__id = card_id
        self.__holder = card_holder

        # a dictionary that will contain the full book : loan time, updated in later function
        self.__loan = {'tttt': {},"uuuu":{}}

    def return_book(self, book):
        del self.__loan[book]
        print('returned')
        return


def main():
    # command = input("Command: ")
    command = "R"

    # borrowed books main list to check if book borrowed or not
    borrowed_books = ["tttt","aaaa"]

    if command == "R":

        # book = input("Book code: ")
        book = "tttt"
        if book not in borrowed_books:
            print('This book has not been borrowed by anyone')

        else:
            borrowed_books.remove(book)
            print('book returned')

            library_book = Librarycard('card_id', 'you know holder')
            print("before  ",library_book._Librarycard__loan)
            library_book.return_book(book)
            print("after ",library_book._Librarycard__loan)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

```
C:\Users\sharp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe C:/Users/sharp/Desktop/project/testid.py
book returned
before   {'tttt': {}, 'uuuu': {}}
returned
after  {'uuuu': {}}

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: you should check the element before del or pop. I edit my answer just now.

Comment: Now the error is gone, but the self object still containing the book on the ID that borrowed the book, so basically the function is there but not deleting the book from the dictionary.

Comment: I did a test on my pc ~~ so the result :  tttt has been deleted.

Comment: That is interesting because I re-tried your method again and still did give me the errors, I think it might be some clashing from my side in functions, but thanks again alot to your assist!

Answer (score 0):

A couple of issues here.

First, the book that comes from the input is a **string** and not the actual book class. So, when calling `book.return_book(book)`, the compiler is looking for a method `return_book` in the string class (which is obviously not there).

Second, borrowed_books is never being updated in the main class, so the user will never return any books.

Third, instead of using del in the Class, use `self.__loan.pop(book)`. It is the inbuilt python function, and is a better way to remove the book.

Finally, there are a lot of camel case issues

Here is what the final code *may* look like.

```py
class LibraryCard:
    def __int__ (self, card_id, card_holder):
        self.card_id=card_id
        self.__card_holder=card_holder
        self.checked_out={}
    def return_book (self, book_id):
        popped = self.checked_out.pop(book_id, "Book was already returned, or was never checked out")
        if (popped != "Book was already returned, or was never checked out"): 
            print("Book returned: "+popped)
        else:
            print(popped)
    def isCard(self, id, name):
        return self.card_id==id and self.__card_holder==name


def main():
    cards = {}
    while (true):
        command = input("To check out a book press \"C\", to return a book press \"R\" (without the quotes):\t")
        print("Whether or not you have an account, please follow the instructions below")
            card_id=input("Enter your card id:\t")
        user_name=input("For security purposes, enter your name:\t")
        if (user_id not in cards):
            print("Welcome to Library Services")
            cards[user_id] = LibraryCard(card_id, user_name)
        if (not cards[user_id].isCard(user_id, user_name)):
            print("Wrong user name or user id, please retry")
            continue
        if (command=="C"):
            book=input("Enter the name of the book you would like to check out: ")
            cards[user_id].checked_out[book]=3
            print("Checked out successfully!")
        else:
            book=input("Enter the name of the book you would like to return: ")
            cards[user_id].return_book(book)
```

Comment: Thanks karma for your comment, I think I should have mentioned more, that the code I wrote is part of the full code and there is parts i skipped writing it as they are not relevant to where exactly I have the issue.
Second part, my struggle is to specifically return the book without using any ID from the user, as happens in actual libraries, and then update the object that contains loans in the class, If I was able to use ID it would have been easy, but I am required not to.

Comment: The way it works in libraries is each book has a unique code, even if the book is the same. So, if 2 books were the same, they would still have different codes. I suggest making a book class in that case, and using a list, not a dict.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed it in a way that I added a new variable that connects the class in the main function, then did a loop that runs into all the cards inside the class keys of the class, and finally with that key I activated the return book function.

The main issue was that I didn't create an access for which *ID* I wanted to delete the *book* from. but once activated with the for loop I was able to reach all *ID'S* object and delete the book from the one that has it.

Here is how the code looks like in the specific parts concerning this problem:

```
    def main():
    
        #function that reads the text file and assign the card ids and card holders as a 
        #dictionary.
        library = read_card_data("library.txt")
    
    
         while True:
         command = input("Command: ")
    
            if command == "R":
    
                book = input("Book code: ")
    
                if book not in borrowed_books:
                    print('This book has not been borrowed by anyone')
    
                else:
                    del borrowed_books[book]
    
                    for card in library.keys():
                        library[card].return_book(book)
```